# Retrieve search string from text box on master page for internal search

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently, I have a text box and a button on my master page for entering and submitting a search string. The search is internal to my website. The user would enter the search string then click on the search button. The search button redirects to the search results page. When the search results page is loaded, it currently searches through the controls on the previous page to find the search string textbox to retrieve the search string.

This all works fine except when a search is entered from the log-in page due to an exception: *The current user is not allowed to access the previous page*.

So I'm wondering what might be a better way to retrieve the search string. I'd prefer not to clutter the redirect url with it. I'm not adverse to storing it in the Session collection but am having trouble figuring out how to get it there before the Page load event occurs.

Below is the pertinet code:

From the master page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" PostBackUrl="~/Search.aspx" ImageUrl="~/Graphics/btn_search.png" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
```

From the search results page:

```
private string getSearchTextBoxText(Control ctrl)
{
    if (ctrl.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            string s = getSearchTextBoxText(child);

            if (s != null)
                return s;
        }
    }
    else if (ctrl.ID == "SearchTextBox")
    {
        return ((TextBox)ctrl).Text;
    }

    return null;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.Debug("Entering " + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    string lastSearchText = Label1.Text;
    string searchText = null;

    try
    {
        searchText = PreviousPage != null ? getSearchTextBoxText(PreviousPage) : getSearchTextBoxText(this);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Exception occurred attempting to retrieve the search string", ex);
    }
...
```

Comment: You have a search text box on master page and you want its text in any child page? Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct this by adding the following to the Web.config file in the Account directory:

```
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Once that is added, then the previous page is accessible and the search string can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your question properly, but from title I can assume that you want the text that is in master page's text box in child page. Right? For that try out this code :

```
TextBox SearchTextBox= (TextBox)this.Master.FindControl("SearchTextBox");
string searchText = SearchTextBox.Text;
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for; how to access the master page controls. Thank you!

Comment: @russ please up vote if it is useful, it will increase my reputation and inspire me to help to resolve these kind of issues to others. Thanks.

Comment: After working with this, I decided it doesn't quite answer my question, though it definitely helped. Now, using Master, it is easy to get the value of the TextBox. However, the problem with not being able to retrieve it when a search is initiated from the log-in page persists.

That is, to get the search string, I need to access the TextBox from the previous page. Now, I know to use PreviousPage.Master.FindControl, however, in this case, the PreviousPage object is inaccessible and the above mentioned exception still occurs.

Comment: @russ It is quite funny that login page also includes search text box. :), and stackoverflow is site to get the solutions, not whole code of your project.

Comment: seriously, was that necessary? Why is it funny to have a search box on a master page? Where did I ask anyone to code my project?

Comment: @russ Whenever you ask a question, people reply it with their best knowledge. If you get the solution then you tick it as accepted as best solution. Now if your requirement gets changed, THEN IT IS NOT FAULT OF THE PEOPLE WHO ARE SPENDING THEIR VALUABLE TIME TO GET SOLUTIONS FOR THE PROBLEM OF PEOPLE LIKE YOU. FIRST YOU HAVE ACCEPTED MY ANSWER AND NOW YOUR REQUIREMENT IS CHANGED THEN YOU UNMARKED IT. IT AFFECTS MY REPUTATION IN THIS SITE. SO PLEASE BE KIND WITH THE PEOPLE WHO HELPS YOU.

Comment: I never changed the original question. I did think your answer solved it, but then, afterwards, when implementing it, I found it did not answer the question as written. Your answer simplified things, but did not effect the problem as presented. So, of course since what you presented didn't answer the question, I unmarked it as being answered in the hope that you or someone else might have an answer. I do appreciate your help, you taught me something, thank you.

Comment: If it is so then you can check whether the previous page is exists or not, if not then find the control from current page's master page if it is required, Or you can check the page is login page or not via Page's url properties.

Comment: Unfortunately, checking for existence of the previous page is not possible due to exception: _The current user is not allowed to access the previous page_. That is the reason for my question. How to get the search string text when the previous page is not accessible.